# Abrir arquivo de uma pasta da rede

Tags: c#

Olá! Preciso abrir um determinado arquivo localizado em um compartilhamento de pastas feito através do Samba Server no Webmin do Ubuntu. O código abaixo, aparenta-me funcional, porém recebo o código de erro: Usuário ou senha incorretos.

```
Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("\\\\192.168.10.116\\MarcaBus\\Arquivos\\Comprovantes\\arquivo.pdf");
        proc.StartInfo.UserName = "root";
        proc.StartInfo.Domain = "MYDOMAIN";

        string PwString = "Pmjm2018!@#";
        char[] PasswordChars = PwString.ToCharArray();
        SecureString Password = new SecureString();
        foreach (char c in PasswordChars)
            Password.AppendChar(c);

        proc.StartInfo.Password = Password;
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.Start();
```

[image: Código de erro]

Como contorno essa situação?

Comment: Defina um limite para o password na declaração char[10]. Pode ter um caractere de espaço, ou algo resumindo a zero sem ser nulo. Use PasswordChars.Length para contar quantos caracteres tem para ter certeza que a senha não tem alguma coisa a mais que você não definiu.

Comment: Ao invés de usar \\\\ pode usar @ antes do path. Assim: ProcessStartInfo(@"\\192.168.10.116\......). o @ é usado para ignorar possíveis caracteres de escape.

Comment: Algo sobre como usar StartInfo: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.startinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema poderá estar na forma como a *password* está a ser construída na `SecureString`.

Experimente criar o seguinte método (não esquecer o `using System.Security`):

```
using System.Security;

public static SecureString ConvertToSecureString(this string password)
{
    if (password == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("password");

    unsafe
    {
        fixed (char* passwordChars = password)
        {
            var securePassword = new SecureString(passwordChars, password.Length);
            securePassword.MakeReadOnly();
            return securePassword;
        }
    }
}
```

Depois utilizá-lo na codificação da *password* ao tentar executar o processo/abertura do ficheiro com dados seguros:

```
string PwString = "Pmjm2018!@#";
SecureString secString = PwString.ConvertToSecureString();

var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    WorkingDirectory = @"\\192.168.10.116\MarcaBus\Arquivos\Comprovantes",
    FileName = "arquivo.pdf",
    UserName = "root", 
    Password = secString,
    Domain = "MYDOMAIN",
    UseShellExecute = false,
};

Process.Start(processInfo);
```

---

Mais informação e detalhes na questão colocada no **SOen**: [Starting a process with a user name and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908993/starting-a-process-with-a-user-name-and-password)

Comment: Continua apresentando o mesmo erro

Comment: Então é melhor retirar a resposta como aceite, porque não resolve o seu problema :/. No entanto, confirme se a informação de acesso está correta.